# Looking for a more general methode for dequeuing UITableViewCells

Tags: swift, xcode

Researching about this topic I found following code:

```
protocol ReusableView {

      static var reuseIdentifier: String { get }
}

extension ReusableView {

       static var reuseIdentifier: String {
           return String(describing: self)
    }
}
extension UITableViewCell: ReusableView {}

extension UITableView {

func dequeueReusableCell<T: UITableViewCell>(for indexPath: IndexPath) -> T {
    guard let cell = dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: T.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? T else {
        fatalError("Unable to Dequeue Reusable Table View Cell")
    }

    return cell
  }
}
```

[Like here suggested](https://cocoacasts.com/dequeueing-reusable-views-with-generics-and-protocols)

My problem is, despite all of the prototype cells defined within storyboard have unique ReuseIdentifiers, the T.reuseIdentifier is always the same: UITableViewCell.

Even when I define following code

```
class c1 : UITableViewCell {}
class c2 : UITableViewCell {}
class c3 : UITableViewCell {}
```

and assign c1,c2,c3 to three prototype cells, the return value still will be UITableViewCell.
So the shown example seems a good way to generalize the topic but something is missing.

This my code calling for calling the dequeue method:

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    let place = places[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = place.name
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(place.timestamp)"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you are calling the new `dequeueReusableCell` method? I feel like you are not calling it correctly.

Comment: Check the update above.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what kind of table view cell you want when you call the method:

```
let cell: c1 = dequeueReusableCell(for: indexPath)
```

This is also mentioned in the later parts of the linked tutorial:

> Remember that we leverage generics and type inference. We want to
>   dequeue a `WeatherDayTableViewCell` instance, not a `UITableViewCell`
>   instance. But how should the compiler know that we want to dequeue a
>   `WeatherDayTableViewCell` instance? The compiler tries to infer the
>   type of the cell constant we define in `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.
>   It sees that we `return cell` from `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` and,
>   by inspecting the method definition, it infers that cell should be of
>   type `UITableViewCell`. The compiler is correct. The solution is very
>   simple. When we declare the cell constant, we need to explicitly
>   specify its type. The compiler then understands that the
>   `dequeueReusableCell(for:`) method should return a
>   `WeatherDayTableViewCell` instance.

Also, I think using `String(describing: self)` is a bad way of getting the class name. If `self` implements `CustomStringConvertible` and has a custom `description` property, this could break your code. A better way is to use:

```
return String(describing: Self.self)
```

Comment: I thought this suggestion would it make possible to define several prototype cells with unique identifiers without dequeuing the cells with endless if/else or switch statements checking the indexPath.row/section

Comment: @frameworker That is not the point of the tutorial you linked. The point is that because cell identifiers are strings, you are likely to make typos in them in code. Using this approach avoids writing string literals, and also avoids casting the returned cell to the correct type. I am not sure if what you want is possible or not, without lots of if/elses.

Comment: I want to have the tableView/dequeReusableCell method which knows itself from where its cells comes from respectively what its identifier is. So currently state of the art seems code like this: let theCell = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ) ? "Cell" : "Cell2". This is not fancy I mean.